# outer join operator not allowed in operand of OR or IN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, oracle10g

I want to display data related to a folder, even if related tables doesn't contain data.

```
SELECT *
FROM FOLDER fold

-- Other joins skipped for brevity

-- Display null values if no data found in INVOICE items
LEFT OUTER JOIN INVOICE inv                       -- Works if INNER JOIN, but I need OUTER
    ON inv.DOS_CODE_ID = fold.dos_code_id 
    AND inv.ECO_CODE_ID IN ('2', '4')             -- Works if I remove those
    AND inv.SER_CODE_ID IN ('Item 1', 'Item 2')   -- two criterias

-- Display null values if no data found in CMD_LOC items
LEFT OUTER JOIN CMD_LOC loc
    ON inv.dos_code_id = loc.dos_code_id 
    AND inv.cmd_code_id = loc.cmd_code_id
    AND inv.cmd_dt_creat = loc.cmd_dt_creat
          
WHERE fold.DOS_CODE_ID = 'ABC123';
```

By doing that I get this error message:

> ORA-01719: Outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN
>
> ORA-02063: preceding line from [My DB link]

I understand what the issue is and can fix it by replacing `LEFT OUTER JOIN INVOICE` by `INNER JOIN INVOICE` but I want to get folder data even if there is no data in `INVOICE` table.

How can I create the query?

---

**EDIT:**

Screenshot of the issue:
[image]

---

**EDIT 2 + WORKAROUND:**

To prevent the error message we can create `UNION` queries, but in my case that will create 2² queries for each criteria in my `IN()` arrays.

To bypass the problem I encapsulated the `JOIN` inside a view and then `JOIN` the view inside my query. That works but is not nice, as part of the query is outside and the view is never used elsewhere in the database.

Comment: You were used field dos.DOS_CODE_ID but I want to know doc is which table’s alias name.

Comment: That is `fold.DOS_CODE_ID`, I have updated my question

Comment: Your join syntax as shown is fine. I suspect your error is somewhere else  -either you have a missing parentheses or a (+) operator somewhere that is causing issues.

Comment: No the query is not accepted by Oracle. If I remove the two `IN` criterias in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN INVOICE` that works, so I have to find a way to add those criterias in the `JOIN`

Comment: check this info on this error code http://ora-01719.ora-code.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the `()` to all On arguments

```
  SELECT *
    FROM FOLDER fold

    -- Other joins skipped for brevity

    -- Display null values if no data found in INVOICE items
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INVOICE inv
        ON (inv.DOS_CODE_ID = fold.dos_code_id 
        AND inv.ECO_CODE_ID IN ('2', '4') 
        AND inv.SER_CODE_ID IN ('Item 1', 'Item 2') )

    -- Display null values if no data found in CMD_LOC items
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CMD_LOC loc
        ON (inv.dos_code_id = loc.dos_code_id 
        AND inv.cmd_code_id = loc.cmd_code_id
        AND inv.cmd_dt_creat = loc.cmd_dt_creat)

    WHERE dos.DOS_CODE_ID = 'ABC123';
```

---- thid give me a result in my database of corse

```
[SELECT *
FROM m_product fold
  -- Other joins skipped for brevity
  -- Display null values if no data found in INVOICE items
LEFT OUTER JOIN c_INVOICE inv
ON inv.AD_ORG_ID   = fold.AD_ORG_ID
AND inv.C_ORDER_ID IN ('1000001', '1000002')           -- If I remove those two
AND inv.DOCSTATUS IN ('CO', 'BR') -- criterias that works
  -- Display null values if no data found in CMD_LOC items
LEFT OUTER JOIN c_order loc
ON inv.C_ORDER_ID     = loc.C_ORDER_ID
AND inv.AD_CLIENT_ID   = loc.AD_CLIENT_ID   
AND inv.AD_ORG_ID   = loc.AD_ORG_ID

WHERE fold.M_PRODUCT_ID = '1000000'
```

and this is the result

[image]

Comment: its wrok to me for oracle and without ()

Comment: i hav replace all with null and its work try to replace all your arguments with null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1635807/glautrou i edit my example and i give a test with my data base its work perfect

Comment: It does not fix my issue, please have a look at the screenshot in my updated question. I am using Oracle 10g Enterprise

Comment: i m using it two .... take a look on this article  http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01719.php

Comment: I have updated my question. In my case it is not possible to create  `UNION` queries as that will cause too much performance problems. As a workaround I created a view to perform a `JOIN` on the query. But I would like to konw why my original query doesn't work and yours work to mark your question as Answer.

Comment: simply i work with distance database and when i ask its admin he tell me is 11G Oracle and not 10G like i tell you before so may be this not work on 10G ... may be not sur

Answer (score 0):

Workaround 2:

I got this same issue today and found another workaround...
the Instr function. It will only work if your ECO_CODE_ID's are from 0-9. :)

```
SELECT *
FROM FOLDER fold

-- Other joins skipped for brevity

-- Display null values if no data found in INVOICE items
LEFT OUTER JOIN INVOICE inv                       -- Works if INNER JOIN, but I need OUTER
    ON inv.DOS_CODE_ID = fold.dos_code_id 
    AND ( INSTR(inv.ECO_CODE_ID,'2')+INSTR(inv.ECO_CODE_ID,'4') > 0 )
    AND ( INSTR(inv.SER_CODE_ID,'Item 1')+INSTR(inv.SER_CODE_ID,'Item 2') > 0 )
    --AND inv.ECO_CODE_ID IN ('2', '4')             -- Works if I remove those
    --AND inv.SER_CODE_ID IN ('Item 1', 'Item 2')   -- two criterias

-- Display null values if no data found in CMD_LOC items
LEFT OUTER JOIN CMD_LOC loc
    ON inv.dos_code_id = loc.dos_code_id 
    AND inv.cmd_code_id = loc.cmd_code_id
    AND inv.cmd_dt_creat = loc.cmd_dt_creat

WHERE fold.DOS_CODE_ID = 'ABC123';
```